# Merge two arrays into one flat array by extracting 3 elements at a time from each

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, merge, slice

I have two arrays. For example:

```
 $arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9];
 $arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
```

How can I combine them to general array by taking per 3 elements from every array? The output should be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

The main idea is taking per 3 elements. Later when I understand the algorithm, the arrays will have objects, not digits. I need to understand how I can to combine two arrays by taking per 3 elements from every array.

Comment: Merge the array and then sort them. Two minutes on google.com will show you how.

Comment: The main idea is combining per 3 elements. Later when I understand the algorithm, the array will have objects, not digits. I need to understand how I can to combine two arrays by taking per 3 elements from every array.

Comment: For me, I prefer the idea of people asking for help when they have yet to show code attempts cause everyone starts from the beginning at one point

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry for this. I use Wordpress (WP_Query) and I need to combine arrays of objects to one (by 3) for specific output there. So I've decided to describe here as simple as I can without WP functions and different WP syntaxis. Therefore seems that I didn't try anything but it is not true. Sorry again. Next time I will be more attentitive. And thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This came to mind...

Just keep looping while either array has any elements.

Suck the first three elements from each array and push them into your result array until there is nothing left in the two arrays.

Seems simple enough to me. :)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aGImR))

```
$arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9];
$arr2 = [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

$result = [];
while ($arr1 || $arr2) {
    array_push($result, ...array_splice($arr1, 0, 3), ...array_splice($arr2, 0, 3));
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 4,
  4 => 5,
  5 => 6,
  6 => 7,
  7 => 8,
  8 => 9,
  9 => 10,
  10 => 11,
  11 => 12,
  12 => 13,
  13 => 14,
)
```

---

If you don't want to mutate your original input arrays, this will do: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/h3k5J))

```
$result = [];
for ($i = 0; isset($arr1[$i]) || isset($arr2[$i]); $i += 3) {
    array_push($result, ...array_slice($arr1, $i, 3), ...array_slice($arr2, $i, 3));
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So like the comment said you can just merge then sort. The reason for this and why it is a recommended approach is due to the fact that the sort and merge operations apply on the highest level key-value and do not affect sub-objects/arrays inside the merged array.

```php
<?PHP    
    $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
    $array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
    $result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    sort($result);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

However, if you really wanted to do an "every 3 elements" method. You can do it by
looping from 0 to n_smallest_length array and then just appending the rest of the larger array to the end and then sorting in 2 places to make sure the next set is being appended into an already sorted array

1. sorting the array at each iteration
2. or sorting at the end

```php
<?PHP
    $array_one_size = sizeof($array1);
    $array_two_size = sizeof($array2);
    $smallest_size = $array_one_size < $array_two_size ? $array_one_size : $array_two_size;
    $result = array();
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $smallest_size; $i += 3) {
        $result_tmp = array($array1[$i], $array1[$i + 1], $array1[$i + 2], $array2[$i], $array2[$i + 1], $array2[$i + 2]);
        $result = array_merge($result, $result_tmp);
        sort($result); 
    }

    if ($smallest_size == $array_one_size) {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_slice($array1, $i);
    } else {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_slice($array2, $i);
    }

    sort($result);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Note: Also, the case shown above works really well with easily sortable elements. If you want to go for a more complex element array then just replace the `sort($result);` lines with a custom sorting algorithm that fits your needs.

Comment: ...simpler my way.  I was not going to undelete my answer until the OP showed a coding attempt.  but you forced my hand.  We don't actually know if `sort` is desired or is relevant.  the numeracy in the sample data is probably used by the OP to reflect the way the output should be ordered -- not that the real input will have values like this.

Comment: no worries, I just saw he wanted an algorithm and assumed he did not want one with a lot of built in functions, because it seems like he is trying to learn the basics still.

Comment: However, I really like your solution @mickmackusa, I completely forgot about that trick with the while loop!

Comment: @mickmackusa "We don't actually know if the sort is desired or is relevant." -> that is why I added the Note at the end

Comment: no? I like the simplicity of your answer